# How do I display all selected options from multiselect listbox in edit view on Grails?

Tags: grails, select, groovy, listbox, multi-select

I am new to Grails development and have been having issues with `<g:select>`  when it is used for a multi-select list. In my form, users can select between 1 to 6 options in a multi-select list box. They can then go back to an edit view to make changes.

The form successfully saves all the options that were selected, but if more than one option was selected, the listbox won't display that *any* were selected in the edit view. If only one option was selected however, it is displayed in the edit view correctly.

Could someone please give me some idea of how to fix it so that all selected options are displayed in edit view? (Running Grails 2.0.3)

Here is my `<g:select>` code in the GSP:

```
<g:select selected="true" multiple="true" name="securityGroup"
          from="${['Mainframe', 'Finance', 'EDI', 'Item Master', 'Risk Management', 'Telecomm']}"
          value="${MFAdminInstance?.securityGroup}"/>
```

Domain:

class MFAdmin {

```
static constraints = {

    name(nullable:false, blank:false, unique:true)
    briefDetail(nullable:false, blank:false)
    details(blank:false)
    recsz(nullable:false, blank:false)
    securityGroup(nullable:false, blank:false)
    files(nullable:false, blank:false)
    begJCL(nullable:false, blank:false)
    addJCL1(nullable:true, blank:true)
    addJCL2(nullable:true, blank:true)
    endJCL(nullable:false, blank:false)

}

String name
String briefDetail
String details
String recsz
String securityGroup
Integer files
String begJCL
String addJCL1
String addJCL2
String endJCL
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try being more explicit to the g:select tag that your value ${MFAdminInstance?.securityGroup} is a list.  I'd suggest something like this:

```
${MFAdminInstance?.securityGroup?.toList()}
```

I was able to mock your code with something like:

```
<g:form action="update">
<g:select selected="true" multiple="true" name="securityGroup"
          from="${['Mainframe', 'Finance', 'EDI', 'Item Master', 'Risk Management', 'Telecomm']}"
          value="${bars}"/>
 <g:submitButton name="submit" />
 </g:form>
```

And within my action foo2 that handles the post:

```
def update() {
    render(view: 'foo', model: [
            bars: params.securityGroup.toList()
    ])
}
```

As you can see when I defined the list `bars` to be used in the gsp, I had to explicitly tell it that params.securityGroup is a list.  Without that `toList()` at the end, the behavior was the missing selection for multiple select.

EDIT:

..inMFAdminInstance...

```
List<String> securityGroup
```

In your controller, you could store the selected post values to your domain with something like...

```
def mf = new MFAdminInstance()
mf.securityGroup = params.securityGroup?.toList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I could not get your suggestion to make it work. I think it may have something to do with my domain (posted above in edit)

Comment: Ah so your domain securityGroup is just a "String".  That's your problem.  When you post a multi select to your controller there will be multiple values of securityGroup and you can obtain it from params.securityGroup which will be a list as seen in my solution.  But you need to store it as a list in your domain.  See my update for how you could change your domain to specify that securityGroup is a List.